# ZKM - How to skip/ignore unusable classes?

Tags: java, android

From ZKM Logs:

> FATAL ERROR: Attempt to use "obfuscate" statement at line 132 with unusable classes : Class 'javax.naming.Binding' not found while looking for method 'getObject()' in class 'javax.naming.Binding' which is referenced in class 'C:\Users\AndroidProjects\myProject\myProject\build\libs\myProject.jar!org/bouncycastle/cert/dane/fetcher/JndiDANEFetcherFactory$1.class'. Check the classpath option and reopen classes. (1a)

I included the dependencies in the jar so that the library is standalone and the user does not need to import a lot of stuff. However, this error pops up when using ZKM.

How to make ZKM ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a javaFX class.

You could just add the missing jar to the classpath in the Zelix script and then it will work:

Example from https://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/langZKMScript.html

```
An example using every statement and parameter with color coding


/*****************************************************************************/
/* Sample ZKM Script using every statement and parameter                     */
/*****************************************************************************/

classpath   ".;c:\jdk1.4.0\jre\lib\rt.jar"
            "C:/path to java/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar" // this is what I had to add
            "Path to the jar that wasn't found"; // you could add the jar containing the Binding class
```